# How to define default Entity Manager for Symfony Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I am setting up an App with multiple databases, each database has its own entity manager.

When I query the data and specify the entity manager for the entity, it works fine.

I cannot create a form that has a relationship (both entities use the same entity manager).

I get the following error when trying to render a form to create a new entity

> [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant App\Repository\Admin\Item\ItemsRepository, class App\Entity\Item\Items.

```
// App/Entity/Item/Items.php
/**
 * Items
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=App\Repository\Admin\Item\ItemsRepository)
 * @ORM\Table(name="items")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Items
{
....
}
```

```
// App/Repository/Item/ItemsRepository.php
namespace App\Repository\Admin\Item;

use App\Entity\Item\Items;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Items|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Items|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Items[]    findAll()
 * @method Items[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class ItemsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
...
}
```

```
#config/package/doctrine.yaml   
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Default'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Default'
            item_service:
                connection: item_service
                mappings:
                    ItemAlias:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Item'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Item'
                        alias: ItemAlias
```

Overall file structure:

```
src
  Controller
    Admin
      Item
        UnitConversionsController.php
  Entity
    Item
      Items.php
  Repository
    Admin
      Item
        ItemsRepository.php
```

I'd be happy if there was a way to manually define the entity manager that the Type class is using to pull the related data for populating the form.

How do I get symfony to recognize a default entity manager for a directory of entities?

Comment: The error mentions a constant, that seems like a clue. Have you tried quoting the FQCN, `repositoryClass="App\Repository\Admin\Item\ItemsRepository"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mentions a constant, that seems like a clue. Quote the FQCN so it's a string instead:

```
repositoryClass="App\Repository\Admin\Item\ItemsRepository"
```